# jpype.getDefaultJVMPath() fails when I try accessing JVM from python3

Tags: jvm, jpype

I am currently using Python3, java8, jpype 0.6.3 version on windows10.
`jpype.getDefaultJVMPath()` fails with an error :

```
raise JVMNotFoundException("No JVM shared library file ({0}) "
jpype._jvmfinder.JVMNotFoundException: No JVM shared library file (jvm.dll) found. Try setting up the JAVA_HOME environment variable properly.
```

My `JAVA_HOME` points to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_241`

If I try starting JVM directly by passing the jvm.dll `path("C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll)` python program crashes.
I have already given executable permission to .dll file

Could anyone please help me fix this issue for the above system specifications

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that your JVM architecture (32 bit) does not match your Python (64 bit).  This would cause the symptoms you are describing.

Comment: How do I check that the JVM and Python match?

Comment: There are detailed instructions of how to debug this issue under project/debug directory in the jpype repo.   Unfortunately the full instructions depend on the type of machine and are rather involved so I can't post them all here.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the shared code I was using required a specific version of one of the drivers. I still don't understand it all enough to explain why that was but with the older driver version (from a colleague) everything works!

Answer (score 0):

```
from jpype import *
startJVM("/home/user_name/Downloads/ideaIC-2022.2.3/idea-IC- 222.4345.14/jbr/lib/server/libjvm.so", "-ea")

java.lang.System.out.println("hello world")
shutdownJVM()
```

This works for me
set the path manually

```
startJVM("/home/user_name/Downloads/ideaIC-2022.2.3/idea-IC- 222.4345.14/jbr/lib/server/libjvm.so", "-ea")
```

If this path is not correct for you
Search for this file libjvm.so  inside partition computer on linux
Then copy the file path